# Convert curl request into http request?

Tags: linux, http, curl, postman

I am trying to convert the curl request below into an HTTP request for the postman tool. The postman tool might not really matter in this question. Please tell me how I can convert curl to http.

```
curl -X POST -i 'https://a-webservice.com' -H X-apiKey:jamesBond007 -d MESSAGE-TYPE="pub.controller.user.created" -d PAYLOAD='a json object goes here!'
```

**What I tried/learned:**
- Set headers content-type: json/application, X-apiKey

- from curl docs, -d option means we need to set content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Postman lets me set the request body using ONLY 1 of the 4 options- form-data, x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, binary. Can you show how I can convert the two -d options of curl into these options ?

I am confused how to put it all together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is just the same as a query string, so:

```
MESSAGE-TYPE=pub.controller.user.created&PAYLOAD=a json object goes here!
```

To confirm, you can dump the request data with `curl` itself, using  [the `--trace-ascii` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace-ascii):

```
curl --trace-ascii - -X POST -i 'https://a-webservice.com' \
  -H X-apiKey:jamesBond007 -d MESSAGE-TYPE="pub.controller.user.created" \
  -d PAYLOAD='a json object goes here!'
```

`--trace-ascii` takes a filename as an argument but if you give it `-` it will dump to `stdout`.

The output for the above invocation will include something like this:

```
=> Send header, 168 bytes (0xa8)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: Host: example.com
0024: User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
003d: Accept: */*
004a: X-apiKey:jamesBond007
0061: Content-Length: 73
0075: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00a6:
=> Send data, 73 bytes (0x49)
0000: MESSAGE-TYPE=pub.controller.user.created&PAYLOAD=a json object g
0040: oes here!
== Info: upload completely sent off: 73 out of 73 bytes
```

So the same as what’s confirmed in the answer at [Convert curl request into http request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218219/convert-curl-request-into-http-request/42218477#42218477) that uses `nc`, but confirmed just using `curl` itself, with the `--trace-ascii` option.

Comment: Thanks ! I did not do all the ascii and file stuff. But, I simply looked at the last three lines of your output. I chose the "raw" option under body, i.e. i set the body of the request to MESSAGE-TYPE=abc.deg=f&PAYLOAD={a json object}. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Postman. But I captured what's being sent in a file named `/tmp/ncout`. Based on this, we see that the Content-Type being sent is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, as you determined, and that the payload being sent is `MESSAGE-TYPE=pub.controller.user.created&PAYLOAD=a json object goes here!`.

Does that help?

```
alewin@gobo ~ $ nc -l 8888 >/tmp/ncout 2>&1 </dev/null &
[1] 15259
alewin@gobo ~ $ curl -X POST -i 'http://localhost:8888/' -H X-apiKey:jamesBond007 -d MESSAGE-TYPE="pub.controller.user.created" -d PAYLOAD='a json object goes here!'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
[1]+  Done                    nc -l 8888 > /tmp/ncout 2>&1 < /dev/null
alewin@gobo ~ $ cat /tmp/ncout 
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
X-apiKey:jamesBond007
Content-Length: 73
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

MESSAGE-TYPE=pub.controller.user.created&PAYLOAD=a json object goes here!alewin@gobo ~ $
```

Comment: So basically, I have to have two key value pairs for application/x-www-form-urlencoded ? that is message-type and payload ?

Comment: Yes, x-www-form-urlencoded encodes the POST data the same way as if it were a GET--with key/values URL-escaped, and & separating them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do this urlencode with python:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> data = {'MESSAGE-TYPE': "pub.controller.user.created", 'PAYLOAD': 'a json object goes here!'}
> from urllib import urlencode
> urlencode(data)
PAYLOAD=a+json+object+goes+here%21&MESSAGE-TYPE=pub.controller.user.created
```